# formal notations

Tags: notation

I have a problem of expressions with proper notations. If you can help me to give a formal and exact expression, it will be helpful.

The specific description is

Given a set of non-negative variable $c_{m,k}\in C$, there exists $\max\{c_{m,k}\}$ and $\min\{c_{m,k}\}$. I would like to express most elements in $C$ are close to $\max\{c_{m,k}\}$ and the rest are close to $\min\{c_{m,k}\}$.

What is the best/formal way to express that?

Comment: You have to decide what exactly *most* means.